SvelteKit API requests parallel processing
//routes/quotes/+page.js
export const load = async ({fetch}) => {
    // First Fetch Request to Quotes
    let quotes = [];
    const fetchQuotes = async () => {
        const resultQuotes = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/quotes?limit=10');
        const quotesData = await resultQuotes.json();
        const quotes = quotesData.quotes
        console.log("Q" + quotes);
        return quotes;    
    }

    // Second Fetch Request to Comments
    let users = [];
    const fetchUsers = async () => {    
        const resultUsers = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users?limit=10');
        const userData = await resultUsers.json();
        const users = userData.users;
        console.log("U" + users);
        return users;    
    }

    return {
        quotes: fetchQuotes(),
        users: fetchUsers()
    }

<!--routes/quotes/+page.svelte -->
<script>
  export let data;
  const { fetchQuotes } = data;
  console.log(data);
</script>

<h1>Quotes</h1>

{#each fetchQuotes as item}
  <h2>{item.quote}</h2>
  <p>{item.author}</p>
{/each}



API calls in +page.js work ok but nothing is passed to +page.svelte for listing.
I'm new to Svelte so probably a silly mistake??
Errors:
Unrecoverable HMR error in <+page>: next update will trigger a full reload
Uncaught (in promise) Error: {#each} only works with iterable values.


export let data;
const { fetchQuotes } = data;

When destructuring you have to use the name of the key which was just quotes
Both fetchQuotes and fetchUsers are async so the results of the calls will first be a Promise that will resolve to the return value
Either await the result in +page.js so the #each block gets an iterable value (the page will be blank until the data is loaded)
return {
        quotes: await fetchQuotes()
       }

or handle the Promise in +page.svelte with an #await block
<script>
  export let data
</script>

<h1>Quotes</h1>

{#await data.quotes}
    Loading quotes...
{:then quotes}
  {#each quotes as q}
    <h2>{q.quote}</h2>
    <p>{q.author}</p>
  {/each}
{/await}


SvelteKit will await promises in the object returned from load() for us, so the data props passed to +page.svelte components will not contain promises, only the values they resolve to.

Thank you so much, both options work fine

@PeppeL-G I think there was a time when only nested promised were streamed https://geoffrich.net/posts/conditionally-stream-data/#:~:text=If%20you%20return%20a%20nested,data%20in%20as%20it's%20available which now seems to be the case for all levels https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises

@Corrl, I stand corrected; you're right. The docs says that only in SvelteKit 1.x, promises at the top level of the returned object are automatically awaited. Thanks for pointing it out!
